# Click on page number of a grid

Tags: vba, excel

I need to use VBA code to click the href "2" (second page)
since there are no ID name, I am unable to use

```
  ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_searchResults_searchResultsGrid_imgExportExcel").Click option

  <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_searchResults_searchResultsGrid_pagingButtonsPanel">
      <span class="gridPagerPageLinkCurrent" 1 ></span>
      <a class="gridPagerPageLink" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$searchResults$searchResultsGridPAGE', 2)" target="_self" 2 ></a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
  ie.document.getElementById( _ 
 "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_searchResults_searchResultsGrid_imgExportExcel") _
 .getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
```